# Populating Select options using Knockout.js with MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am a beginner with knockout.js. I am having trouble getting a select's options to populate in an MVC 4 view. Here's my code.

(Break point in the controller shows data populating the viewbag correctly. The list contains only two fields per item: shown in the creation of the SelectList in the controller.)

The controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Brewery> breweries = new List<Brewery>(_commonProvider.GetBreweryList());
    ViewBag.Breweries = new SelectList(breweries.AsEnumerable(), "BreweryCode", "BreweryDescription");
    return View();
}
```

The view:

```
/*** html stuff ***/
<select class="ui-select" id="BrewerySelect" name="BrewerySelect" data-bind="options: GetBreweries,
                                                                             optionsText: BreweryDescription,
                                                                             optionsValue BreweryCode,
                                                                             value: selectedBrewery,
                                                                             optionsCaption: Select a Brewery"></select>

/*** javascript stuff ***/
@section footer {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/viewscripts-js")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var config = {
            GetBrewery: '@Url.Action("GetBrewery")',
            GetLine: '@Url.Action("GetLine")',
            GetUrl: '@Url.Action("GetUrl")'
        };

        var data = {
            Brewery: "@ViewBag.Breweries",
            Date: '@DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")'
        };

        var viewModel = DashboardReportViewModel(config, data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


    </script>
}
```

The ViewModel

```
var DashboardReportViewModel = function (config, originalData) {
    var self = this;

    self.GetBreweries = ko.observableArray([originalData.Breweries]);
}
```

I've also tried:

```
var DashboardReportViewModel = function (config, originalData) {
    var self = this;

    self.GetBreweries = ko.observableArray([]);

    var loadBreweries = function () {
        self.GetBreweries(originalData.Brewery);
    }

    loadBreweries();
}
```

Comment: I can't find `DashBoardViewModel` in your code .You have `DashboardReportViewModel `

Comment: That was a lightbulb moment, but when fixed, the list still did not populate. I'll edit it in the code here.

Comment: Could you show what the js `data` var looks like after it has rendered? I.e.: how the `<script>` tag in the footer reaches the browser.

Comment: I think I've found the issue actually. When sending the Viewbag.Breweries variable to the ViewModel it is being sent as a basic string "System.Web.Mvc.SelectList". I think I'll need to remove the viewbag assignment in the controller and execute an ajax call to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, the ViewBag will hold an object or array of objects, but when you call that ViewBag property from the view it will call `ToString` on that property.

Consequently,

```
"@ViewBag.Breweries"
```

Is the same as writing

```
"@ViewBag.Breweries.ToString"
```

And unless you've overriden `SelectList.ToString()` then all you'll get out of this is the fully-qualified class name.

The preferable approach - as you've now done - is to expose the `Breweries` as retrievable data (JSON, XML, *etc.*) and retrieve this asynchronously, but you could also add an extension method called, say, `SelectList.ToJson()` which returns the contents of the `SelectList` formatted in such a way that you can easily output it in `<script>` tags on a view.

Answer (score 0):

After discovering that sending the Viewbag simply resulted in a string being passed, I moved the controller BreweryList building to a seperate ActionResult and used ajax to call it.

Changes

View:

```
 <select class="ui-select" id="BrewerySelect" name="BrewerySelect" data-bind="options: GetBreweries,
                                                                              optionsText: 'Text',
                                                                              optionsValue: 'Value',
                                                                              optionsCaption: 'Select a Brewery'"></select>
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    { 
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetBreweries()
    {
        List<Brewery> breweries = new List<Brewery>(_commonProvider.GetBreweryList());
        SelectList breweryList = new SelectList(breweries, "BreweryCode", "BreweryDescription");
        return Json(breweryList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
var DashboardReportViewModel = function (config, originalData) {
    var self = this;

    self.GetBreweries = ko.observableArray([]);    

    var loadBreweries = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: config.GetBreweries,
            type: "GET",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                self.GetBreweries(data);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    };
    loadBreweries();

};
```

Nothing else changed.